# Leer un archivo de texto y comparar su contenido con un arraylist en java

Tags: java, arraylist

Mi preguntas es la siguiente, como puedo comparar el contenido de un archivo de texto con el contenido de un arraylist? por ej: tengo un método que realiza una búsqueda de archivos en una carpeta especificada y lo levanta en un arraylist, lo que necesitaría saber como podría hacer para comparar lo que hay dentro del array con lo que hay dentro del archivo de texto. Osea dentro del archivo txt tengo almacenado los nombres de localidades con la siguiente estructura: **PDA01 - Buenos Aires**

Como hago para saber que dentro de mi array tengo un archivo que empieza con la extructura **PDA01** e indicar por msj que ese archivo pertenece a **Buenos Aires** me explico?

Leo el archivo.

```
public void leer(){
        try{
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Sucursales.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String strLinea;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
                // Imprimimos la línea por pantalla
                System.out.println (strLinea);
            }
            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        }catch (Exception e){ //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Busqueda de archivos

```
public void buscarArchivo(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        ArrayList<String> arrayArchivos = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i]);
                } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                    if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                        contador++;
                        arrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        leerArchivos.leer();

                    }
                }
            }
            arrayArchivos.clear();
        }
    }
```

Hasta ahora tengo eso, solo me lista lo que tengo dentro del archivo txt, pero nose como realizar la comparacion si dentro del arraylist existe un archivo con la estructura **PDA01** que sea perteneciente a **BUENOS AIRES** o **PDA02** sea perteneciente a **X** provincia. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas hacer, pero si tienes una información en un texto plano, y sabes su estructura, que comentas que es algo como PDA01-Buenos Aires por cada linea, puedes probar a hacer un .split("-") y tendrás en un array el PDA01 en una posición y la ciudad en otra, implementando un poco mas de código puedes manipular la información, siempre que sepas como esta estructurada .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E logrado solucionar mi problema de la siguiente manera.

Tengo mi método **leer()** el cual resivo como parametro un arraylist

```
    public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
                    ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();
                    Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap();

                    try {
                        // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
                        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Sucursales.txt"));
                        // Creamos el objeto de entrada
                        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                        // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
                        String contenido;
                        // Leer el archivo linea por linea
                        while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    //                      Partimos el String.
                            String[] separador = contenido.split(",");
    //                      Agregamos al Map.
                            mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
                        }
        //              Vaciamos el array en cada vuelta para que no sea un acumulador.
                        keyArray.clear();
                        //Recorremos el arrayList
                        for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                            String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                            String codSucursal = separador[0].replace("PDA", "").trim();
//                          Agregamos al array temporal.
                            keyArray.add(codSucursal);
                        }
//                      Recorremos el map.
                        for (String key : mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet()) {
                            int encontrados = this.contarTicketPorSucursal(keyArray, key);
                            if (encontrados > 0) {
                                System.out.println("Tienes " + encontrados + " ticket pendiente de la sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key));
                            }
                        }
                        // Cerramos el archivo
                        entrada.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
                        System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

Contamos la cantidad de archivos que hay de una misma sucursal.

```
          private int contarTicketPorSucursal(ArrayList<String> keyArray, String key) {
            int contador = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.size(); i++) {
                if (keyArray.get(i).equals(key)) {
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            return contador;
        }
```

Espero que a alguien le sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

BuefferedReader tiene un metódo llamado lines() que te devuelve un stream que puedes recorrer y comparar con el contenido de arraylist.

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));

buffer.lines().forEach() //java 8
```